# Parse JSON to Excel - Pandas + xlwt

Tags: pandas, xlwt

I'm kind of half way through this functionality. However, I need some help with formatting the data in the sheet that contains the output.

My current code...

```
response = {"sic2":[{"confidence":1.0,"label":"73"}],"sic4":[{"confidence":0.5,"label":"7310"}],"sic8":[{"confidence":0.5,"label":"73101000"},{"confidence":0.25,"label":"73102000"},{"confidence":0.25,"label":"73109999"}]}


# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(response), orient='index')

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

The output is as follows...
[image]

What I want is something like this...

[image]

I suppose that first I would need to extract and organise the headers.
This would also include manually assigning a header for a column that cannot have a header by default as in case of SIC column.

After that, I can feed data to the columns with their respective headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop over the keys of your json object and create a dataframe from each, then use `pd.concat` to combine them all:

```
import json

import pandas as pd

response = '{"sic2":[{"confidence":1.0,"label":"73"}],"sic4":[{"confidence":0.5,"label":"7310"}],"sic8":[{"confidence":0.5,"label":"73101000"},{"confidence":0.25,"label":"73102000"},{"confidence":0.25,"label":"73109999"}]}'

json_data = json.loads(response)

all_frames = []
for k, v in json_data.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    df['SIC Category'] = k
    all_frames.append(df)

final_data = pd.concat(all_frames).set_index('SIC Category')

print(final_data)
```

This prints:

```
              confidence     label
SIC Category                      
sic2                1.00        73
sic4                0.50      7310
sic8                0.50  73101000
sic8                0.25  73102000
sic8                0.25  73109999
```

Which you can export to Excel as before, through `final_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')`